# Notification when database gets a new entry on VB .net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Is there a way to display a notification everytime a entry gets added to a mysql database? For each entry there is a status column and 1 is the default value which is a New entry and i want to display a notification every time the database gets a new entry so I can go see on the site we have setup(each entry is a servicedesk ticket) to review it. I'm using VB.net
Should also be of concern i have the showing the notification part worked out

Comment: you'd need some long-running process or thread which checks in the database (via a query) at regular intervals. There's no way AFAIK to have mysql "notify" another application.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is querying the database and whenever the total rows number changes that means a entry changed and therefore it throws the notification but im having trouble in the checking phase

Answer (score 0):

For anyone curious, i got it working myself, the code i used was

```
Dim curCount = data_set2.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) 'gets the current count

If curCount > prevCount Then 'if there are more than the previous count, that means a entry was added
    NotifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation
    NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = 
    data_set.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
End If
prevCount = data_set2.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) 'sets the previous count to the current one for checking
```

This is all on a timer and it has worked for me while testing stuff out, it might be a bit bad now but its the first piece that worked.

Comment: Its pretty easy to write a notifier for MySql which is a bit more certain, particularly for just one table.  If a row is added and deleted in the interim, your method will miss it.